# For Loop with If/If Else statement with simple math functions need help storing

Tags: r, function, loops, math, storage

I am trying to create a simple For Loop that will run through a column of numbers in my dataframe and perform three different simple math functions on the column of numbers based on simple conditions.

Basically if my RiB value is less than or greater than a constant (pos_RiB <- 0.011, neg_RiB <- -0.011) I want the function I wrote to do the math on the RiB value and store it, if the RiB value falls inbetween the constants, I want the RiB value to just store as it is.

Here is my code:

```
#Set empty storage vector
vec <- vector()
#Set positive and negative RiB constants for loop

#Create functions for different atmospheric stability conditions 

RiB <- sp3_join_a$RiB 

Unstable <- function(RiB){
 (1-(16*RiB))^0.75
}


Stable <- function(RiB){
  (1-(5*RiB))^2
}

Neutral <- function(RiB){
  RiB == RiB
}

#Condition constants
pos_RiB <- 0.011
neg_RiB <- -0.011

#For Loop
for(i in (sp3_join_a$RiB)){
  if (sp3_join_a$RiB > pos_RiB){
   vec[i] <- Unstable(sp3_join_a$RiB[i])
  }
  else if (sp3_join_a$RiB < neg_RiB){
  vec[i] <- Stable(sp3_join_a$RiB[i])
  }
  else (sp3_join_a$RiB < pos_RiB && sp3_join_a > neg_RiB)
  vec[i] <- Neutral(sp3_join_a$RiB[i])
}

sp3_join_a$vec <- vec
```

In my dataframe sp3_join_a$RiB values are numeric and look like (0.15099768  0.13389330  0.08309406  0.06137715  0.06234167  0.05491064  0.04332422  0.05927553  0.03774791  0.04653331).

Comment: Hi Alex, I've updated my answer below to give a few solutions: your for loop, base R and data.table

Comment: Thank you for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you can try nested `ifelse`

```
sp3_join_a <- within(sp3_join_a,
                     vec <- ifelse(RiB > pos_RiB,
                                   Unstable(RiB),
                                   ifelse(RiB < neg_RiB,
                                          Stable(RiB),
                                          Neutral(RiB))))
```

Comment: Thank you this almost works! It works to compute and store the some of the values but not all.

Comment: @Alex sorry, I had a typo in `Neutral(RiB)` (I wrote it as `Rib`). Maybe you can retry

Comment: I noticed that and corrected it in my attempt, It gave me NaN for a decent bit of numbers but correctly computed the rest.

Comment: @Alex Where does `NaN` appear? What's the the `RiB` value for that problem?

Comment: NaN appears where the statement should be applying the math functions to the dataframe and the column of values. For example the RiB value of ".015099768" gets a NaN when it should be greater than pos_RiB and computed to "0.3482491" and stored in the dataframe. It will do the math for some of the numeric values and than just produces NaN for the rest.

Comment: @Alex this is because in your function `Unstable`, `1-16*RiB` might be negative, which will give you complex value when you have `(1-16*RiB) ^(3/4)`, thus resulting in `NaN`

Comment: Ita wherever your value is >1/16 ... isn't it a mathematical problem?

Comment: @rg255 Yes, it's a math issue

Comment: Ok thank you for finding that, I figured at this point something in the logic of the math problems was failing. How can I fix that issue?

Comment: ```NaN``` values are being generated for RiB values that meet the criteria to go through the ```Stable``` function as well, which is confusing.

Comment: OMG thank you all for all the help and attention. I had a sign flip issue in the math functions. The problem is resolved, cheers!

Comment: @Alex Great you addressed the problem. If you think my answer is helpful, please feel free to accept it, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Using data.table you can chain expressions and do conditional subsetting and sub assign values by reference, avoiding a for loop

```
library(data.table)
# dummy data
sp3_join_a <- data.table(RiB = runif(100, -0.015, 0.015))

pos_RiB <- 0.011
neg_RiB <- -0.011
```

The solution is then:

```
# Chaining expressions with (sub)assignment on conditional subsets 
sp3_join_a[, vec := RiB][RiB > pos_RiB, vec := (1-(16*RiB))^0.75][RiB < neg_RiB, vec := (1-(5*RiB))^2]
```

---

Note you can use standard base R syntax for a very similar approach, I just used data.table because its more efficient.

```
sp3_join_a[,"vec"] <- sp3_join_a[,"RiB"] 
sp3_join_a[sp3_join_a[,"RiB"] > pos_RiB, "vec"] <- Unstable(sp3_join_a[sp3_join_a[,"RiB"] > pos_RiB, "RiB"])
sp3_join_a[sp3_join_a[,"RiB"] < neg_RiB, "vec"] <- Stable(sp3_join_a[sp3_join_a[,"RiB"] < neg_RiB, "RiB"])
```

---

To use your loop there are some adjustments I'd suggest to make

```
# send RiB to vec column as is before the loop
sp3_join_a$vec <- sp3_join_a$RiB

# i needs to reference by position (1:nRows)
for(i in 1:length(sp3_join_a$RiB)){
# assign straight to the dataframe 
  if (sp3_join_a$RiB[i] > pos_RiB){
   sp3_join_a$vec[i] <- Unstable(sp3_join_a$RiB[i])
  }
  if (sp3_join_a$RiB[i] < neg_RiB){
   sp3_join_a$vec[i] <- Stable(sp3_join_a$RiB[i])
  }
}
```